# $l_{\infty}$ is the quotient of $l_{1}(\aleph_{1})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cardinals

I wonder if  $l_{\infty}$ is the quotient of $l_{1}(\aleph_{1})$.

If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to suspect that this might be so?  Do you have any ideas as to how a quotient structure could even be constructed?

Answer (score 5):

The statement is equivalent to the Continuum hypothesis. Indeed, taking a   quotient cannot increase the density character, and the density character of $l_\infty$ is $c$. This gives one implication.

If $\aleph_1=c$, then   pick a dense subset of cardinality $\aleph_1$ in the unit ball of $l_\infty$. Map the standard basis vectors of $l_1(\aleph_1)$ bijectively to the points of this subset, and extend by linearity.

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you show more details?

Comment: @bruce I gave enough, the rest is up to you. Also, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/